# When we create an object of class A in python and it contain suppose two instance variable x=10 and y=11

Tags: python, oop

When we create an object of class A in python and it contain suppose two instance variable x=10 and y=11. Does that object of class A will contain only reference x and y of the instance variables and value 10 and 11 as an object will stored at different location in heap? So as everything in python is an object instance variables are also object so class A object will contain only references x and Y and actual object will be stored at a different location in heap? is my understanding correct?

Comment: Can you show the code that implements this scenario?  In particular, how you have defined `A` and how the instance variables are getting their values?

Comment: Yes, if an instance of `A` has 10 and 11 as its attributes, those attributes are only references, the actual data of the numbers 10 and 11 are not stored in the instance of `A`.

Comment: You may want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html, which includes helpful diagrams that are too bothersome to create here.

Comment: In fact, in Python there is only one integer with value 10, and all integers equal to 10 are the same object. (Try `5 + 5 is 10`. The operator `is` checks object identity, ie if things are at the same memory location.)

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. Assuming the following code

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 11

a = A()
```

there is an object of type `A` (referenced by the name `a`), and two objects of type `int` (`10`, referenced by `a.x`; and `11`, referenced by `a.y`).

(There is also an object of type `type`, referenced by `A`., and an object of type `function`, referenced by `A.__init__`.)

Comment: And many more objects, such as `A.__mro__`, `a.__dict__`, the string `'x'`, and so on. Python really creates a *lot* of objects even in very simple code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to limit the answer to immediately visible objects.